# Why do I get this error when wanting to use router useNavigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, higher-order-components

I learn React and can't understand how to fix this simple error:

I have a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apple-basket-with-router-v6-and-withauthorization-forked-wwoby?file=/src/session/WithAuthorization.jsx).

I have this code:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prefer-stateless-function */
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthUserContext from './context';

const WithAuthorization = condition => Component => {
    class withAuthorization extends React.Component {
        doStuff = event => {
            const navigate = useNavigate();
            navigate('/', { replace: true });
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
                    {authUser => (condition(authUser) ? <Component {...this.props} /> : this.doStuff())}
                </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
            );
        }
    }

    return withAuthorization;
};

export default WithAuthorization;
```

It's not working this line is the reason `const navigate = useNavigate();` and the error is this:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

All I want is to navigate away when `WithAuthorization` detect a bad path.

Should I instead use maybe Redux to do this handling, it feels so ridiculous to send a Redux action?

Answer (score 1):

The error is very self explain, you need to use the hook in function component and on the top level (you cant initilase it inside a function) so try this:

```
const WithAuthorization = condition => Component => {
 return props => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const doStuff = event => navigate('/', { replace: true });
    
    return (
            <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
                {authUser => (condition(authUser) ? <Component {...props} /> : doStuff())}
            </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
          );
  } 
};
```

Comment: dunnu but I still get even using your code this  " React Hook "useNavigate" is called in function "withAuthorization" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook functio"

Comment: I move the `useNavigate()` to outer function and then get " React Hook "useNavigate" cannot be called inside a callback"

Comment: This is so strange I read the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/) and this should work

Comment: I think this might be a bug so I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7721)

Comment: @Kid iv updated the code can you try now?

Comment: I get [the same](https://snipboard.io/rJDVXf.jpg) error I'm afraid

Comment: If I remove router hook `useNavigate` my app is working good this must be some funky stuff that router is doing I try to look into the code but it's advanced

Comment: I [created a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apple-basket-with-router-v6-and-withauthorization-forked-wwoby?file=/src/session/WithAuthorization.jsx) that [show](https://snipboard.io/kvHznU.jpg) this error to. Hope you have time to help out

Comment: Should I instead use maybe Redux to do this handling it feel so ridicules, to send a Redux action??